# Woocommerce customize single product view

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making woocommerce customizations. But I'm not good enough to now how to get attributes of a product. I also want to get the link to a attribute archive page.

I put the woocommerce folder in my theme folder. This way I can make custom behaviour. In this woocommerce folder is a file theme-name/woocommerce/single-product/tabs/tabs.php

This file is use the print product description. After that I put in the code snippet to print category name and it's description. I also want it to print the attribute of the product. (preferably with the link to it's archive page).

Is there a way to use part of snippet to echo the attribute of the product?

```html
global $post;
    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'product_cat' );
    $attribute_names = array( 'Producten');
        foreach ( $attribute_names as $attribute_name ) {
                    $taxonomy = get_taxonomy( $attribute_name );
                    if ( $taxonomy && ! is_wp_error( $taxonomy ) ) {
                            $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post->ID, $attribute_name );
                            $terms_array = array();
                    if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
                            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                                   $archive_link = get_term_link( $term->slug, $attribute_name );
                                   $full_line = '<a href="' . $archive_link . '">'. $term->name . '</a>';
                                   array_push( $terms_array, $full_line );
                            }
                            echo $taxonomy->labels->name . ' ' . implode( $terms_array, ', ' );
                    }
            }
        }
    foreach ($terms as $term) {                             
        $name = $term->name;
        $desc = $term->description;

        break;
    }

echo $name;
echo '<br>';
echo $desc;
```

Comment: which are the attributes you want ?

Comment: I have a atribute term named colors in my product variation, with attributes, red, green, blue etc...

Comment: I have given you some code, not tested but you will get some way from that.

Answer (score 0):

You need to code something like this, not exactly like this, you need some modification here, I have only posted some code parts from my work, there I was retrieving weight and price .In argument you can add category if you need. and let me know after using this code if you are getting any error or problem, as I have not tested it.

```
  <?php
         $arg = array('posts_per_page' => -1, 'numberposts' => -1, 'post_type' => 'product');
        $products = get_posts($arg);
        <?php $product_obj = new WC_Product_Factory();  ?>  <?php if ($products): ?>
        <?php foreach($products as $product): ?><?php $product = $product_obj->get_product($product); ?>

       <?php if ($product->product_type == 'variable'): ?>
        <?php $children = $product->get_children( $args = '', $output = OBJECT ); ?>

        <?php
        foreach ($children as $key=>$value) {
            $product_variatons = new WC_Product_Variation($value);
            if ( $product_variatons->exists() && $product_variatons->variation_is_visible() ) {
            $variations[$value] = $product_variatons->get_variation_attributes();
                }
```